# Optimise writing of *.d.ts file

Tags: typescript

I am currently learning typescript with react and have recently come across this new thing called a .d.ts file. Is there such thing called the optimised way of writing this file or is it up to the developer to create the standards? If there is a standard, may I ask if I am writing it properly? I am only trying to use the function enquiry screen function in my typescript. Thanks.     :-)

**This is the jsx code**

```
let enquireJs;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  const matchMediaPolyfill = mediaQuery => {
    return {
      media: mediaQuery,
      matches: false,
      addListener() {
      },
      removeListener() {
      },
    };
  };
  window.matchMedia = window.matchMedia || matchMediaPolyfill;
  enquireJs = require('enquire.js');
}

const mobileQuery = 'only screen and (max-width: 767.99px)';

export function enquireScreen(cb, query = mobileQuery) {
  if (!enquireJs) {
    return;
  }

  const handler = {
    match: () => {
      cb && cb(true);
    },
    unmatch: () => {
      cb && cb();
    },
  };
  enquireJs.register(query, handler);
  return handler;
}
```

**My own .d.ts file**

```
import enquireJS = require('enquire.js');

export const mobileQuery = 'only screen and (max-width: 767.99px)';

export function enquireScreen(cb: any, query = mobileQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.d.ts` files are declaration files that contain only type information. These files don't produce .js outputs; they are only used for type checking. TypeScript automatically finds type definitions under `node_modules/@types`, so there's no other step needed to get these types available in your application.

You could also create your own types folder inside `tsconfig` under `"typeRoots" : ["./typings"]` or under `include`. For example, you could have a type declaration as well inside a `d.ts` file.

```
declare type status = 'PENDING' | 'ACTIVE'
```

and if tsconfig has a path to this `d.ts` file, this type will be available through your TypeScript application.

I guess you `d.ts` code could be:

```
declare const mobileQuery = 'only screen and (max-width: 767.99px)';
declare function enquireScreen(cb: any, query = mobileQuery);
```

and this file path could be included inside your `tsconfig` as I described above.